# Lookup multiple slack user ids at once using email addresses

Tags: slack-api

Slack has a users.lookupByEmail API (https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail) which can lookup a single user ID based on a single email address.

When wanting to start a multi-party DM is there any way that anyone has found to resolve a set of email addresses to a set of user IDs using a single call?

Answer (score 0):

Make a single call to [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) to get all users incl. their email addresses. And then iterate through the list to get the matching users IDs.